# Return object from observable inside another observable

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, observable, rxjs5

I try to fetch data from 3 different REST end points. The data model consists of main data and has advanced Array with 2(might be more in the future) Objects. I want to inject an Array with options into each of advanced Objects, based on REST endpoint specified in each of them. Everything works and is returned from Observable as Object, except appended options, that come as Observables.

Simplified data:

```
{
 simple: {
   param: "searchQuery",
 },
 advanced: [
  {
   param: "food",
   optionsModel: {
     url: "http://address.com/food",      
     }
  },
  {
   param: "drinks",
   optionsModel: {
     url: "http://address.com/drinks",
     }
   }
  ]
}
```

food and drinks have the same structure consisting of Objects with name and id:

```
 {
  data: [
   {
     name: "DR1",
     id: 1
   },
   {
     name: "DR2",
     id: 1
   },
   ...
  ]
 }
```

In my data model I don't have options[] array, so I inject it manually. Service:

```
 searchConfiguration$: Observable<SearchConfiguration> = this.http
  .get(this._configURL)
  .map((config) => {
      let configuration = config.json();
      let advancedArray = configuration.advanced;

      if(advancedArray) {
        advancedArray.forEach(advanced => {
          advanced.options = [];
          advanced.options = this.http.get(advanced.optionsModel.url)
             .map((r: Response) => r.json().data
        })
      }
    return configuration;
  })
```

Parent component:

```
getSearchConfig() {
  this.searchConfiguration$ = this._bundlesService.searchConfiguration$;
}
```

Then I have async pipe in the html to subscribe to Observable. How can I get my options appended to advanced as actual Arrays and not as a stream?

**Edit - Solution**

Thanks to martin's answer, the solution is to flatten both streams and connect them in the end with forkJoin()

```
  searchConfiguration$: Observable<SearchConfiguration> = this.http
  .get(this._configURL)
  .map((config) => config.json())
  .concatMap((configuration) => {
      let observables = configuration.advanced.map((advanced) => {
        return this.http.get(advanced.optionsModel.url)
          .map((r: Response) =>  r.json().data)
          .concatMap((options) => advanced.options = options)
      });
    return Observable.forkJoin(observables, (...options) => {
      return configuration;
    })
  });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I didn't test it but I think you could you something as follows:

```
searchConfiguration$: Observable<SearchConfiguration> = this.http
  .get(this._configURL)
  .map((config) => config.json())
  .concatMap(configuration => {
    var observables = configuration.advanced.map(advanced => {
      return this.http.get(advanced.optionsModel.url)
         .map((r: Response) => r.json().data);
    });

    return Observable.forkJoin(observables, (...options) => {
      configuration.options = options;
      return configuration;
    });
  })
```

Comment: this helps me a lot and I'm getting all advanced options as expected, the problem is that I would like to get them appended to the whole object - where `.map((config) => config.json().advanced)` maps directly to advanced.

Comment: @Tina333 Ah, I see. Then it gets a little more complicated. I'm using `forkJoin()` to wait until all `this.http` complete and then update the `configuration` with their result.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I managed to solve it. So it was me explaining wrong what I wanted - to append each option Array to each advanced Object, based on each url(and not to whole Object, as I explained). I managed to do that by adding one more concatMap() on `observables.` to your suggestion. I added modified code in the question.